# Python/Selenium- Class element cannot be clicked

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from this page: https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/#over-under;2

Here I am trying to expand all of the "compare odds" fields, which are contained in this HTML:

```html
<div class="table-container">
            <div class="table-header-light even"><strong><a href="" onclick="page.togleTableContent('P-1.00-0-0',this);return false;">Over/Under +1 </a></strong><span class="avg chunk-odd-payout">93.4%</span><span class="avg chunk-odd nowrp"><a href="#" onclick="page.getActiveTableSet().togleMatch(this,'4j5hgx1tl1gx34x0',2);return false;" xparam="odds_text">5.63</a></span>
                <span
                    class="avg chunk-odd nowrp"><a href="#" onclick="page.getActiveTableSet().togleMatch(this,'4j5hgx1tkucx34x0',2);return false;" xparam="odds_text">1.12</a></span><span class="odds-cnt">(3)</span><span class="odds-co"><a class="more" href="" onclick="page.togleTableContent('P-1.00-0-0',this);return false;">Compare odds</a></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-container" style="display: none;">
            <div class="table-header-light"><strong><a href="" onclick="page.togleTableContent('P-1.25-0-0',this);return false;">Over/Under +1.25 </a></strong><span class="avg chunk-odd-payout"></span><span class="avg chunk-odd nowrp"></span><span class="avg chunk-odd nowrp"></span>
                <span
                    class="odds-cnt">(0)</span><span class="odds-co"><a class="more" href="" onclick="page.togleTableContent('P-1.25-0-0',this);return false;">Compare odds</a></span></div>
        </div>
```

The part I am trying to access is the following:
span class="odds-co">Compare odds

I have tried all of the following:

```
#odds_rows = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('more')
# odds_rows=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".more")
# odds_rows=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='more']")))
odds_rows= WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".more")))
#odds_rows=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "more")))

In order to subsequently loop click through the identified fields:
for i in odds_rows:
    #browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", i)
    i.click()

However already in the step of identifying the fields I am getting a timeout error on all WebDriverWait attempts except for 
odds_rows=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "more")))
This option yields only one result:
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7cbc57173a57aadbc115264dff8ca620", element="3654f928-bca4-4033-9566-da9e6aa6294b")>]
```

However this result is not clicked subsequently.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/#over-under;2;0.50;0")

driver.maximize_window()
odds_rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.table-header-light')))


for i in odds_rows:
    count = i.find_element_by_xpath('./span[@class="odds-cnt"]')
    elem = i.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(text(),"Compare")]')
    txt = count.text

    if txt != '' and len(elem):
       elem = elem[0]
       driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
       elem.click()
```

The issue is the row with count '' is not visible and you cannot click it .

Comment: This worked, thank you! Strangely, even though the individual rows with the over/under odds are expanded now, their HTML is not available when i retrieve the driver.page_source.. Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

if you click on 'Compare odds' you can see the URL that changes from
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/#over-under;2

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/#over-under;2;0.50;0

if you follow clicking you will se that the last part:
2;0.50;0 will increase by 0.5
next is
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/#over-under;2;1.00;0

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/#over-under;2;1.50;0
and continue...

In another way you have this class: "table-main detail-odds sortable" by default is hidden, because there is the data, you DON'T need to click. you can scrape that class
i hope be helpful for you.